# Storing the current timr into a string

Tags: android, time, simpledateformat

I am currently trying to figure out how to use an onClickListener to when pressed, store the current time into a string, to then setText to a TextView in order to give the time to the user and store it for later use.

Should I be using `SimpleDateFormat`to do so? If so, how do I parse that to a string?

Comment: It is entirely dependent on how you want the string displayed. It will likely be something like SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US); sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis));

Comment: Military time, such as ("HH:mm")

Comment: Then just do that in the code I just gave you, just replace the time string I had, `"hh:mm:ss a"`, with what you want.

Comment: currentTimeMillis cannot be resolved or is not a field
That's what I get, I must have overlooked something. Sorry for being bad, I'm very new to this syntax.

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis() <- forgot to add the empty parameter to it. Would be `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US); sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

Comment: I don't think you need to add System.currentTimeMillis() by the way, you may be able to leave it empty but I can't remember :P

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 Button clickButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    clickButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());

        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        myTextView.setText("Current Time: " + timeStamp);

        }
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Wow I was going about it all wrong. I didn't even realize I could set my String to = an SDF, that's how bad I am. EVerything I needed to do was in that one line of code. Thank you. This is perfect.